# Can't contact users privately in Firefox

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

I'm trying to use the Moderator Private Message tool.  I'm able to select a template to use, but when I click on the "Use this template" button, nothing happens.

I'm using Firefox 5.0 on Windows XP Pro, if that helps at all.

**Update:** I just confirmed that this is not working on either Stack Overflow or Meta.

**Update II:** I just downloaded Chrome and tried it and it *does* work.  Adding that to Grace's comment about IE8, this looks like it's only an issue in Firefox.

**Update III:**  Just to give it higher visibility, I'm getting the same error message that Michael Mrozek reported in the comments:

> Error: previewWmd.refreshPreview is not a function
>   Source File: https://stackoverflow.com/users/message/create/XXXXXX
>   Line: 108

Comment: Oi, if this question title had come from anyone other than a moderator, we'd have a field day.

Comment: @Grace: Right after I posted this I wondered if it would get downvotes on the strength of the title alone.  :)

Comment: On a serious note - no repro on Gaming. I can select a template but it will show me the window. IE8 on XP here.

Comment: @Grace: I'm still waiting on that upgrade from IE6 to IE8.  :(  Other issues in IE6 prevent me from even logging in.

Comment: Good heavens, and I thought I had it bad for having to stick with IE8...

Comment: Repro on Programmers with Firefox 3.6.18 on Windows 7.

Comment: Same on Firefox 3.5.8; error message: "previewWmd.refreshPreview is not a function"

Comment: Repro on FireFox 5.0 on Win7 x64 Ultimate for the SO/MSO moderators private messaging tools.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual error is a DOM exception that happens before the exception you quote, resulting from the fact that the editor on that page is initially hidden. Firefox seems to be more strict about allowing access that doesn't make sense when an element is invisible, and the editor code does only a very simple "is this visible" check that failed in this case.

I'm wondering: Has this ever worked? From what I'm seeing, this should have always failed in Firefox if it fails now. Either way, it's fixed after the next build.

Comment: I use Firefox both at work and at home, so I'm certain it used to work.  July 13 was the last time I successfully used the tool, so the change happened at some point in the last week.

Comment: Okay, thanks. In that case it was probably I who broke it :)